# Combobox only fills with last record from database and not all records

Tags: c#, database, list, combobox

I got a problem where I want to fill a combobox with items from a list. The list gets items from my database.

The problem is that the combobox only fills with the last record in database.

**Example**: If I got 5 records in my database with 5 different Id's like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Then the combobox only show me the Id 5, five times. Like this: 5-5-5-5-5. What I want is: 1-2-3-4-5.

It might be a small error and I've tried to research and test different things but nothing have worked. Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

The code below is from my database class where I think the problem is, which fills my list with items from database:

```
    public static List<Product> getProducts()
    {
        List<Product> listProducts= new List<Product>();

        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_Products;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand selectProductNumber = new SqlCommand(@"Select ProductNumber FROM Product", connection);

            SqlDataReader dr = selectProductNumber.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.ProductNumber = dr["ProductNumber"].ToString();
                listProducts.Add(product);
            }
            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
            return listProducts;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the method to fill the combobox and where I use the methods:

```
    private ProductList productList = new ProductList();

    private void FillComboBox()
    {
        comboBox.Items.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < productList.Count; i++)
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add(productList[i].GetProductNumber(" \t "));
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        productList.Fill();
        FillComboBox();

    }
```

From my ProductList class:

```
    public void Fill()
    {
        productList = DB_class.getProducts();
    }

    public Product this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return productList[index];
        }
    }

    public void Add(Product product)
    {
        productList.Add(product);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return productList.Count; }
    }
```

From my Product class:

```
    public string GetProductNumber(string showProductNumber)
    {
        return ProductNumber;
    }
```

Comment: what are the values of listproducts when you debug?  are they 5-5-5-5-5 or 1-2-3-4-5 ?

Comment: When I debug it's like this: First iteration the list is given 1. The second iteration it's given 2-2. The third iteration it's given 3-3-3 and so on. Until 5-5-5-5-5

Comment: Show your code where you assign values after calling getProducts(), it seems the above method is all-right.

Comment: Show how you connect it to the combobox !

Comment: In the Form_Load - you call productList.Fill() - in the ProductList class you call productList = DB_class.GetProducts(). Use this, or whitch reference is productlist points to in fill() method?

Comment: Yes, I use that method from Form_Load to get products from database. Problem is that my combobox only shows last database record like I explained. I can't understand why

Comment: Is the class you use List<product> or your own class with an index, the ProductList class? You should use the List<product> class in form_load - overload the toString() and add it to the combobox as an foreach statement, check my answer !

Comment: I use my own class (ProductList class) with index.

Comment: You should include it in the code, the problem is in your class i think !

Comment: I've included it now!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Change your `FillComboBox` method as follows

```
private void FillComboBox()
{
    comboBox.Items.Clear();
    List<Product> proList = getProducts();
    for (int i = 0; i < proList.Count; i++)
    {
        comboBox.Items.Add(proList[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I explained it bad. I re-edited my question

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it soles your problem.
If you add an "Linq to Sql"(.dbml) file to your project. And simple drag the tables you need from Server Explorer - then you can solve it like this.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var DBcontext = new DBDataContext();

        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";

        comboBox1.DataSource = DBcontext.Items.ToList();

        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        DBcontext.Dispose();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get displaytext
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Text);

        //Get id value
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()); 
    }
```

//If you want your method you should do it like this

```
    class Product
    {


        public string ProductNumber { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ProductNumber;
        }

    }
    private List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
    productList  = GetProducts(); //your sql function.

    private void FillComboBox()
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var p in productList)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(p); 
        }
    }
```